# Is there any way use one set of certificates for several etcd cluster

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

If I have several etcd cluster, simply I should create several certificates for each cluster.

However can I create only one set of certificates for those etcd cluster? Cause it's too complicated when I want scaling the cluster or some other scenarios( to tell the truth I want use only one set of certificates for etcd cluster and kubernetes cluster).

I try to generate server certificate like below, but dosen't work:
`cfssl print-defaults csr > server.json`

`...
    "CN": "coreos1",
    "hosts": [
        ""
    ],
...`

I follow the guide: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/generate-self-signed-certificates.html
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a server certificate and associated key signed by a custom CA that will work on multiple hosts. You will need to specify which hosts the server certificate is good for in the `"hosts": []` section. Note you can also use wildcards, which as the CoreOS guide states at the bottom:

> They will work on any machine. It will simplify certificates routine
>   but increase security risks.